# Hyperlink in RDLC breaks the report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a client side report that is displayed in a report viewer within a webform. The report displays perfectly until I [create a hyperlink within a textbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-url-report-builder-and-ssrs). However, when I try to render the report, it crashes with the following error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.

Nothing fancy is done with the link. The link is static, not altered by any code, and points to an external site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there is an option [`EnableHyperlinks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477096) on the `LocalReport` object that I couldn't find in the designer, but is accessible during runtime:

```cs
reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
```

Once I included this single line the report stopped crashing and the link worked.